# Using a for loop with grep in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, grepl

I am having an issue with my code. I have got a for loop so that it Identifies all "strong" tags in an html document and then identifies the row number of a given word in the html. I want it, for any instances where the row numbers match, to make note of that row number. I have it so far, but if there is an instance of the word outside that of the rows where the strong tag is, it fails

```
url <- readLines("http://afip.gob.ar/contacto")

tagname=NULL
identifier=NULL
IDintag=NULL
rowst=NULL
rowend=NULL
data=NULL

tag <- as.matrix(grep("<strong>",url))
    if(length(tag) > 0)
    {ID <- grep("Telef|Numero",url)
        for(i in 1:length(ID))
        {IDintag[i] <- grep(ID[i],tag)
        }
        for(i in 1:length(IDintag))
        {tagname[i] <- tag[IDintag[i]]
        }
        for(i in 1:length(tagname))
        {rowst[i] <- which(grepl(tagname[i],tag))
        rowend[i] <- tag[rowst[i] + 1,]-1
        data[i] <- toString(url[tagname[i]:rowend[i]])
        }
}
```

This works like a dream but if I change the url to one where the ID terms occur where the strong tag doesn't, it fails for example:

```
url <- readLines("http://www2.le.ac.uk/contact")

tagname=NULL
identifier=NULL
IDintag=NULL
rowst=NULL
rowend=NULL
data=NULL

tag <- as.matrix(grep("<h2>",url))
    if(length(tag) > 0)
    {ID <- grep("Telef|Numero|phone",url)
        for(i in 1:length(ID))
        {IDintag[i] <- grep(ID[i],tag)
        }
        for(i in 1:length(IDintag))
        {tagname[i] <- tag[IDintag[i]]
        }
        for(i in 1:length(tagname))
        {rowst[i] <- which(grepl(tagname[i],tag))
        rowend[i] <- tag[rowst[i] + 1,]-1
        data[i] <- toString(url[tagname[i]:rowend[i]])
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does it fail? What's the input and what's the expected output and in what way do they differ?

Comment: If I search for "Phone" and the tags "<strong>" it will give me two matrices of row numbers if for the matrix related to the phone search there is a row number that isn't in the <strong> matrix it fails